# Spring Roo not updating generated files

Tags: spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] in STS Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100337 with Java 8 and can't get Roo to update the .aj files when I make changes to beans.

The usual of adding `private Integer fubar;` to the bean and saving isn't making it happen either.

Suggestions?

[Update]
Downgrading to Roo 1.2.5-RELEASE works.

[Update 2]
Using the Roo console to add a field generates this message:

```
roo> field number --fieldName snafu --type Integer --class com.intraxinc.pahala.fitservice.models.TraitType
Updated SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\intraxinc\pahala\fitservice\models\TraitType.java
Undo manage SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\intraxinc\pahala\fitservice\models\TraitType.java
```

Comment: Could you check if it works with Java 7?

Comment: Certainly, I'll try that in a bit and report back.

Comment: @eruiz Java 1.7 fails with 1.3.1.RELEASE. How can I get debug level logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logging command to set debug level logging:

```
roo> logging setup --level DEBUG
```

You could activate the development mode with command below:

```
roo> development mode
```

I executed the Pet Clinic script (clinic.roo) and I modified the entities as you said and all worked ... could you provide more info? for example your log.roo file.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the `logging setup --level DEBUG` somehow.  How do you want the log.roo?

Comment: is there a way to get _Roo_ to dump debugging information? `logging setup --level DEBUG` looks like it sets the log4j for the app.

Comment: Some progress. If I copy a model object that Roo won't update Roo has no problem generating the aj files for the `CopyOf...`. This appears to be related to UI generation as the failing model objects include a generated UI. `development mode` isn't showing much information, is there a way to get more from Roo?

Comment: You can download Roo source code, build it, run roo-dev and debug Roo. But I think the quick way is to create and attach here a small Roo sample script that can be used to reproduce your problem. If that's infeasible, using Roo's "backup" command is another alternative and you can attach the resulting ZIP file.